# Using or replacing "fixed" as in placed firmly, without causing confusion or making the sentence longer

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I'm translating a punch list into English and wondering if "fixed" in sentences would cause confusion.

For example, the sentence in the original language is

> Some devices are not fixed.

, whose actual meaning is

> Some devices are not fixed (firmly) to the rack.

, not

> Some devices are not repaired.

With the context I guess readers would know what "fixed" means in the sentence, but I cannot be so sure. Then, I don't want to make the sentence too long to elaborate.

So, how should I use "fix" in those sentences or other words to replace it with?

Comment: I don't think it would be confusing to a speaker of British English. You could say _fixed in place_ or _secured_.

Comment: Affixed is a possibility in AmE.

Comment: So long as there is more context than the standalone sentence, I can't see anybody getting confused. If there is **only** that sentence, then I would assume the incorrect interpretation.You haven't provided the additional context for us to say anything for sure.